# Помогите разделить текст!

Tags: python, split

Имеется текст(код):

```
code = "out('sus')"
```

Имеется список токенов:

```
lpar = "("
rpar = ")"
quot = "'"
out = "out"
```

Нужно разделить код по данным токенам и получить список

```
sp = ["out", "(", "'", "sus", "'", ")"]
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147061/discussion-on-question-by-rodion-morozov---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

Для решения можно собрать в все токены в одно регулярное выражение с `|`

Для создания динамического регулярного выражения нужно воспользоваться [конструктором RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp)

Стоит обратить внимание, что скобки являются специальными символами в регулярных выражениях, поэтому они должны быть предварительно экранированы.

После применения [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), в получившемся массив могут пустые элементы, в случаях, когда разделители в строке идут друг за другом.

Для отсеивания таких элементов можно использовать метод [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var code = "out('sus')";


var lpar = "\\(";
var rpar = "\\)";
var quot = "'";
var out = "out";

console.log(code.split(new RegExp('(' + [lpar, rpar, quot, out].join('|') + ')')).filter(t => t))
```